# Сборка проекта Phonegap Android под конкретную target

Tags: android, phonegap

При выполнении команды `phonegap build android` получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из-за того, что у меня не установлена Android SDK Platform 25. В опциях команды     `phonegap build`, как я поняла, нет никакой возможности указать конкретную версию для сборки. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ сборки проекта Phonegap Android под конкретную target, или target может быть только android-25?